# pycharm cannot find module with installed by pip

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm, flask-sqlalchemy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdJMh.png)

I have tried many ways, but they still can not figure out my problem. Hope for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help or not, if possible then create new virtualenv and install required package again. And change old virtualenv with new one.

Hope this will help.